# variable sphinx filter with PHP

Tags: php, filter, sphinx

i m sorry for my english, i m french, i need your help for one thing please :

**It s about filtering in php sphinx**

this my code :

```
$filtres= array();
 if(isset($_POST['Pharmacie']) and $_POST['Pharmacie'] ="1" ){ $filtres[]= 1;}
if(isset($_POST['Autres']) and $_POST['Autres'] ="8" ){ $filtres[] = 8;}

$varfiltres = 'array('.implode(" , ",$filtres).')';

if($filtres != array()){
    $sphinx->SetFilter('Type', array(implode(",",$filtres)));
}
```

i have error :

Warning: assert(): Assertion failed in \sphinxapi.php on line 850

in case only one variable isset (pharmacie or Autres) that work!

also if i do `$sphinx->SetFilter('Type', array(1,8))` it work!

thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetFilter, takes an array directly. With:

> $sphinx->SetFilter('Type', array(implode(",",$filtres)));

you are first converting the Array to a String, and then putting it in an **new** array. Don't do that :)

This is all that is needed:

```
$sphinx->SetFilter('Type', $filtres);
```